# How to shrink image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that whenever I click on the button, the image on the screen width decrease by 100px, the width of the picture are all 800px here is what I have:

```
var width_of_pic = 800 ;

function shrink() {
  width_of_pic = width_of_pic - 100;
  var image_element= document.getElementById( "image_element_id" ) ;
  image_element.style.width = width_of_pic;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you're assigning to a style, so you have to conform to CSS rules. `... = width_of_pic + 'px';`. no units = invalid assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the ID is correct, you need to specify a unit:

```
image_element.style.width = width_of_pic+'px';
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9su57p9a/)**